# How to clone a MutableSet of entities

Tags: spring, database, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities Task

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
class Task (

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
var id: Long? = null,

@Column(name = "name")
var name: String,

@OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST], orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
    name = "task_settings",
    joinColumns = arrayOf(JoinColumn(name = "task_id")),
    inverseJoinColumns = arrayOf(JoinColumn(name = "settings_id"))
)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "settings_type")
var settings: MutableMap<String?, Settings?>? = mutableMapOf()
    )
```

and TaskHistory:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "task_history")
class TaskHistory (

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
val id: Long? = null,

@Column(name = "name")
var name: String,

@OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST], orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
    name = "task_history_settings",
    joinColumns = arrayOf(JoinColumn(name = "task_history_id")),
    inverseJoinColumns = arrayOf(JoinColumn(name = "settings_id"))
)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "settings_type")
var settings: MutableMap<String?, Settings?>? = mutableMapOf()
```

)

and Settings:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "settings")
class Settings (

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name="settings_value", joinColumns = arrayOf(JoinColumn(name = "settings_id")))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
    @Column(name = "value")
    var settings: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
        )
```

My goal to create entity of TaskHistory based on Task, however whan I try to pass settings like this:

```
fun createTaskHistory(task: Task) {
 val taskHistory = TaskHistory(
       settings = task.settings
       )
}
```

New entity of TaskHistory will have the settings with same id as Tak but I need to create new raw in table settings and settings_value woth the same fields. I've already tried to use `detach` method in EntityManager, but it doesn't work due to key in settings that is String, not Object

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I  found the solution:

```
@Transactional
    fun createTaskHistory(task: Task) {
        var history = TaskHistory(
            settings = task.settings?.mapValues { entry ->
                val originalSettings = entry.value
                val newSettings = Settings()
                if (originalSettings != null) {
                    newSettings.settings = originalSettings.settings.map { it.key to it.value }.toMap().toMutableMap()
                }
                newSettings
            }?.toMutableMap(),
            changedAt = Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
        )
```

In that case TaskHistory will have its own settings with different id